# SAS-3 vs SAS-2 HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sas

What are the main differences between SAS-3 and SAS-2 HDDs? Are there performance differences? Suppose we are talking of 10k rpm disks, ~1 TB, in both cases.

Regards,

Comment: By the way they're not really known as SAS-3/SAS-2 like SATA is, although I can understand why you would - it's more typical to see 6Gbps SAS/12Gbps-SAS etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are no performance differences with that disk type/speed/capacity. Perhaps with an SSD, but for your 7,200/10,000 RPM use case, no.

The [SAS specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI#Characteristics) has a roadmap and the connection fabric is changing while the drive mechanics remain much the same.

Answer (score 2):

SAS-3 supports 12 Gbps while SAS-2 supports 6 Gbps. Many people say that using 12 Gbps disk drives is of no use in present architectures unless there is a flash cache layer in between. 12 Gbps interface can be used with an SSD. See the wikipedia entry on serial attached SCSI.